# Locally convex topological subspace on dual space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

This is an exercise in Lax.
Let $S=\{l_\alpha\}$ be a set of functionals that separate points, show that the weakest topology that all functionals in S are continuous is locally convex.
I know this looks like weak star topology, but S may not be the whole dual space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition a basic neighborhood of $0$ is of the type $\{x: |l_{\alpha_1 }(x)<\epsilon_1,|l_{\alpha_2 }(x)|<\epsilon_2,...,|l_{\alpha_n }(x)| <\epsilon_n)\}$ and this set is convex. Hence any neighborhood of $ 0$ contains a convex neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: How is the condition separating points useful?

Comment: @efhvcjnfdbgefg It is not required for local convexity, but it is required to make the space Hausdorff. Some authors consider only Hausdorff topological vector spaces and that may be the reason why it is given that the functionals separate points.